# Force-disabling cookies in Ruby on Rails 4 (European Union Legislation) until user (re-)accepts ToS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Since I am based in European Union, I believe all the websites I make have to comply with this stupid EU regulation that bans cookie use without user's informed consent (and require the user to opt-in).

My intention is to go "full-overkill" and require user to (re-)accept Terms of Service whenever there's no "_#{app_name}_session" cookie sent from user and (re-)create it only after user clicks [ACCEPT] in said ToS.

Basically, whenever someone visits the app, the user will be forced to explicitly accept ToS or Sign in to be able to use the app/website.

How can I make this happen in in Rails 4?

In PHP I'd just need to add

```
if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
  header("Location: /terms-of-service");
}
```

to the beginning of the `index.php`

I would then need to make sure that the only `session_start()` is at the file that serves the `/terms-of-service` page and there is no other instance anywhere else in the project.

But how to do this with Rails?

Comment: So what exactly you'd need? Redirect user to ToS page every time they visit any page(about, home, etc) until they accept(tick the checkbox and submit) ToS?

Comment: Also, for sign-in, have you implemented any authentication system? or using any gem like devise? As you say it can be either sign-in or acceptance of ToS.

Comment: Well, I want what the PHP script does - I want to check if there's an open session for the browser session and if not, redirect the user to the ToS page (ensuring that user had his explicit informed consent).

Comment: I'm using devise, but with what I said in the previous comment, it is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Bit of a side question for you as I am going through the same process. Are you testing if the visitor is within the EU, and to only do this for them? If so, how are you testing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :validate_toc!

  private

  def validate_toc!
    # check if guest user has not already accepted the toc from session
    redirect_to toc_path, alert: 'Please accept ToC to continue.' if sesion[:tos].nil? || !user_logged_in?
  end
end
```

Note: `sesion[:tos]` is where you set value when user accepts ToS. `toc_path` should be set in routes.rb, for example like this:

```
get '/path/to/toc' => 'pages#toc', :as => :toc
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified your answer and made mine.

Answer (score 1):

I examined @User089247's answer and modified it to my needs

```
before_action :session_check!, except: [:terms_of_service_path]

private

  def session_check!
    redirect_to terms_of_service_path if !session.exists?
  end
```

Basically, if there's no session open for the browser session, the user will be forced to accept the ToS. The ToS page will then create the session unless the user refuses to accept the ToS.

Comment: Actually that's how everybody should be on stackoverflow(SO). Sadly, very few put efforts to understand the logic and instead want the answer to work as is. They don't try to put any effort at their end. I appreciate that you did.