# Rails 4 session variable without a cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

Because of the awesome EU directive on allowing users opt out from having cookies stored I have the following problem.

I have a message that displays at the top of the screen that asks the user to opt in or opt out.

1. if the user opts in, cookies are turned on using rack.policy, and the message is hidden. A cookie variable is set to say that the message should not be shown again for future visits. Perfect
2. If the user opts out. Cookies are disabled, fine. the message is cleared.... and a session variable is set to say don't show the message for this session. This would be fine, but it seems the session variable is saved in the same way as a cookie and the rack policy does not allow it to be displayed. The message therefore flashes up on every single page.

So first, thank you EU. Second, how do I save a "session variable" without saving to a cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force-disabling cookies in Ruby on Rails 4 (European Union Legislation) until user (re-)accepts ToS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669639/force-disabling-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails-4-european-union-legislation-until-us)

Comment: Aren't you allowed to use session cookies without explicit consent?

Comment: its an extension of that question. in that rack policy seems to block all cookies, including session cookies

Answer (score 0):

Unless you try going for something more exotic like local storage offered by the browser, you can't.  [The rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) explicitly states:

All session stores use a cookie to store a unique ID for each session (you must use a cookie, Rails will not allow you to pass the session ID in the URL as this is less secure).

I'm no lawyer, but for what it's worth I believe that law is intended to apply to cookies used for marketing/tracking purposes and does not apply to cookies needed for the site to function like cookies used for authentication or ephemeral storage.  With this in mind, you could use the rails's session cookie for must-have data and use separate cookies for other purposes that your application can disable.

I wouldn't take it as gospel, but [this Wired article](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-05/25/cookies-made-simple) seems to a good job of providing a simplified explanation.